# Count How Many Different Users Have in specific day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a dataframe with pandas:

**looks like that:**

| HostName | Date |
| --- | --- |
| B | 2021-01-01 12:30 |
| A | 2021-01-01 12:45 |
| C | 2021-01-01 12:46 |
| A | 2021-02-01 12:42 |
| B | 2021-02-01 12:43 |
| A | 2021-02-01 12:45 |
| B | 2021-02-25 12:46 |
| C | 2021-03-01 12:41 |
| A | 2021-03-01 12:42 |
| A | 2021-03-01 12:43 |
| C | 2021-03-01 12:45 |

For every day, it should count how many different HostName
there is form the beginning of the day (example: 2021-01-01 00:00) to the specific row

**Example:**
for example lets take the 2021-01-01

| HostName | Date |
| --- | --- |
| B | 2021-01-01 12:30 |
| A | 2021-01-01 12:45 |
| C | 2021-01-01 12:46 |

there is tree rows:

- the first result would be 1 - because its was the first row in the day.(B)
- the second result would be 2 - because  form the beginning of
  the day till this line there is two different Hostname (B,A)
- the third result would be 3 - because  form the beginning of the day till this
  line there is tree different Hostname ( B,A,C)

the end result should look like this:

| HostName | Date | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2021-01-01 12:30 | 1 |
| A | 2021-01-01 12:45 | 2 |
| C | 2021-01-01 12:46 | 3 |
| A | 2021-02-01 12:42 | 1 |
| B | 2021-02-01 12:43 | 2 |
| A | 2021-02-01 12:45 | 2 |
| B | 2021-02-25 12:46 | 1 |
| C | 2021-03-01 12:41 | 1 |
| A | 2021-03-01 12:42 | 2 |
| A | 2021-03-01 12:43 | 2 |
| C | 2021-03-01 12:45 | 2 |

what it try do to but failed:

```
df.groupby(['HostName','Date')['HostName'].cumcount() + 1
```

or

```
def f(x):
    one = x['HostName'].to_numpy()
    twe = x['Date'].to_numpy()
    both = x[['HostName','Date']].shift(1).to_numpy()  
    x['Host_1D_CumCount_Conn'] = [np.sum((one == a) & (twe == b))  for a, b in both]
    return x

df.groupby('HostName').apply(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and cumulative sum:

```
df['Result'] = (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.date)['HostName']
                  .transform(lambda x: (~x.duplicated()).cumsum()))
print (df)
   HostName                Date  Result
0         B 2021-01-01 12:30:00       1
1         A 2021-01-01 12:45:00       2
2         C 2021-01-01 12:46:00       3
3         A 2021-02-01 12:42:00       1
4         B 2021-02-01 12:43:00       2
5         A 2021-02-01 12:45:00       2
6         B 2021-02-25 12:46:00       1
7         C 2021-03-01 12:41:00       1
8         A 2021-03-01 12:42:00       2
9         A 2021-03-01 12:43:00       2
10        C 2021-03-01 12:45:00       2
```

Alternative solution, faster is create helper columns `d` for dates and duplicates per `d` with `HostName` and use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['Result'] = (df.assign(d = df['Date'].dt.date,
                          new = lambda x: ~x.duplicated(['d','HostName']))
                  .groupby('d')['new']
                  .cumsum())
print (df)
   HostName                Date  Result
0         B 2021-01-01 12:30:00       1
1         A 2021-01-01 12:45:00       2
2         C 2021-01-01 12:46:00       3
3         A 2021-02-01 12:42:00       1
4         B 2021-02-01 12:43:00       2
5         A 2021-02-01 12:45:00       2
6         B 2021-02-25 12:46:00       1
7         C 2021-03-01 12:41:00       1
8         A 2021-03-01 12:42:00       2
9         A 2021-03-01 12:43:00       2
10        C 2021-03-01 12:45:00       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` the Date and use `expanding`+`nunique`. The issue is that, currently, expanding only works with numerical values (I wish we could simply do `expanding().nunique()`).

Thus we have to cheat a bit and `factorize` the column to numbers before applying `pd.Series.nunique`.

```
df['Result'] = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date, group_keys=False)
                  ['HostName']
                  .apply(lambda s: pd.Series(s.factorize()[0]).expanding().apply(pd.Series.nunique))
                  .astype(int)
                  .values
                )
```

output:

```
   HostName              Date  Result
0         B  2021-01-01 12:30       1
1         A  2021-01-01 12:45       2
2         C  2021-01-01 12:46       3
3         A  2021-02-01 12:42       1
4         B  2021-02-01 12:43       2
5         A  2021-02-01 12:45       2
6         B  2021-02-25 12:46       1
7         C  2021-03-01 12:41       1
8         A  2021-03-01 12:42       2
9         A  2021-03-01 12:43       2
10        C  2021-03-01 12:45       2
```